# Where does the power go that would have been dissipated once an impedance matching network is in place between say a source and antenna?

Tags: power, radio, transmission-line, reactance

If a load (say antenna) was to be physically difference in impedance to the load, so you decided to place a sort of matching network to match the impedances, where does that now unreflected power go, surely if the actual antenna’s impedance itself hasn’t changed, then it can not itself have a larger signal emitted?

Comment: George, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching the source and the load does actually convert the power available from the source (via impedance transformation) to be used by the load. This can be done with near enough 100% efficiency.

You can design an impedance matching network that achieves this.

Comment: Hi sorry. Forgot to get back to this. If possible could you explain why it means more power is now used by the load (if the loads impedance hasn’t changed) thanks

Comment: If the load hasn't changed it's resistance and, the input signal remains the same why should there be any more power consumed. What I'm trying to say is that your comment doesn't make much sense to me so, maybe try again. What "changing (before and after)" scenario might you be considering?

Comment: Ive done a little more research and think its okay now. Apologies if questions have been strange or obvious  as it is new to me.